# p:dataTable not populating even though the list is not empty

Tags: primefaces

I have been working in primefaces and I created a dialog box that should pop up with a dataTable but it keeps returning no records found even though the list has been populated.

Please see code below:

Java Bean:

```
    public List<accountDetails> accountDetails(String refNo, DatabaseHandler dbase)
{

    try (Connection con = dbase.getDBConnection(DatabaseTypes.TRANSACTION_DATABASE))
    {
        String sql = null;

                //lookup id number or accountNumber   
                if(refNo.substring(0, 5).length() == 13){
            sql =
                "SELECT recID,AccountNo,Balance FROM tblPay@SABCRegistrations WHERE IDNumber ="
                    + refNo.substring(5);
                }else{
            sql = "SELECT recID,AccountNo,Balance FROM tblPay@SABCRegistrations"; // WHERE AccountNo ="
            // + refNo.substring(5);
                }


        ResultSet result = DatabaseHandler.executeQuery(con, sql);
        accList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (result.next())
        {
            accountDetails t = new accountDetails();
                            t.setRecID(result.getString("recID"));
            t.setAccountNo(result.getString("AccountNo"));
            t.setAmount(result.getString("Balance"));
            accList.add(t);

        }
        result.close();
                    System.out.println(accList);
        openDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
            null,
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "An error occurred.", e.getMessage()));
    }

            return accList;

}

public void openDialog()
{
    if (accList.get(0).getAccountNo() != null || !accList.get(0).getAccountNo().isEmpty())
    {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('payDialog').show()");
    }
}
```

xHTML page:

```
     <p:dialog header="Would you like to pay now?" widgetVar="payDialog" resizable="false"  
                      width="1000" id="dialogStatus">  
                 <h:form id="dial">
                <h:panelGrid id="displayStatus" columns="1" cellpadding="4">  


                     <p:dataTable id="fTable" value="#{authBean.accList}" rows="10" 
                                         var="t" widgetVar="feesTable" rowKey="#{t.recID}" 
                                         selectionMode="single"
                                         style="font-size:12px"
                                         resizableColumns="true"
                                         selection="#{authBean.selectedAccount}"
                                         >

                                <p:column headerText="Account No:" style="text-align: left; width: 200px">
                                    <f:facet name="Header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Account No:"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{t.accountNo}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="Amount:" style="text-align: left; width: 250px">
                                    <f:facet name="Header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Amount:"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{t.amount}"/>
                                </p:column>
                         </p:dataTable>


                    <p:commandButton id="btnChangeStatus" value="Pay Now" action="#{authBean.logout}" 
                                     oncomplete="payDialog.hide()"
                                     ajax="true"/>  

                    <p:commandButton id="close" value="Cancel" action="#{authBean.endDialog}"/>

                </h:panelGrid> 
             </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to an [mcve]. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I have edited the code, can you please see if this looks correct.

Comment: If this is an mcve, you should not have a problem if you use a fixed arraylist instead of getting the data from a database. It would work if you remove the headertext from the datatable, it would work if you remove the dialog. And besides that, if you post this, and only this, code in a clean jsf project. How many compile errors do you get? Remove all those, and not by importing the classes, but by eliminating the need for all these classes.